# According to post-2000 Young Earth Creationists / premillennialists, when do (did) we reach year 6000?

Tags: eschatology, young-earth-creation, premillennialism

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennial_Day_Theory) states that Young Earth Creationists are among [premillennialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premillennialism), as well as several early church fathers, who believe that

> human history will continue for 6,000 years and then will enjoy Sabbath for 1,000 years (the millennial kingdom) thus all of human history will have a total of 7,000 years prior to the [new creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_to_Come).

**Question**: What have been the year(s) suggested by post-2000 YEC / premillennialists to be the year 6000 since the creation of earth?

**Optional question**: If they still use the [Ussher Chronology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ussher_chronology) (see also an article on [suggestions for correction](https://answersresearchjournal.org/comments-usshers-date-of-creation/)), how do they correct the calculation, since by straightforward addition year 6000 should have occurred in 1996 AD ?

---

Related question: [Quotations from the early church fathers who support the Jewish year 6000 as significant to eschatology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84736/10672)

Comment: The Lazarus story gives the timing. (1) Jesus heard Lazarus was sick = Adam and Eve ate the fruit. (2) For two days, Jesus stayed = after 2,000 years, God met with Abraham (3) Jesus resurrected Lazarus after 4 days = God resurrected man after 4,000 years. (4) Jesus' resurrection is 33 AD so minus 4,000 = 3968 BC when Adam/Eve ate the fruit. (5) That leaves 2,000 years so the Millenium begins in 2,033 AD.

Comment: (1) When Adam sinned, God killed animal to cover their nakedness = Nisan 14 the passover lamb = Jesus died. (2) God called Abraham out of Ur = Nisan 15 the Exodus when Israel left Egypt. (3) Jesus resurrected = Nisan 16 = man resurrected (Romans 6:8)

Answer (score 1):

**According to post-2000 Young Earth Creationists / premillennialists, when do (did) we reach year 6000?**

> [The Millennial day theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennial_Day_Theory), the Millennium sabbath hypothesis, or the Sabbath millennium theory, is a theory in Christian eschatology in which the Second Coming of Christ will occur 6,000 years after the creation of mankind.
>
> **Proponents**
>
> Early premillennialists included Pseudo-Barnabas,Papias, Methodius, Lactantius, Commodious, Theophilus, Tertullian, Melito, Hippolytus of Rome, Victorinus of Pettau, as well as various Gnostics groups and the Montanists. Many of these theologians and others in the early church expressed their belief in premillennialism through their acceptance of this sexta-septamillennial tradition. This belief claims that human history will continue for 6,000 years.

No matter how one looks at it the world according of the years creation are over 6000 years already, unless some Young Earth Creationists chose to follow the Anno Mundi dating in use by the Jewish calculations. In this case the year 2021 AD is equivalent to the year 5782 [Anno Mundi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Mundi)

> Young Earth creationism (YEC) is a form of creationism which holds as a central tenet that the Earth and its lifeforms were created in their present forms by supernatural acts of a deity between approximately 6,000 and 10,000 years ago. In its most widespread version, YEC is based on the religious belief in the inerrancy of certain literal interpretations of the Book of Genesis. Its primary adherents are Christians and Jews who believe that God created the Earth in six literal days, in contrast with old Earth creationism (OEC), which holds literal interpretations of Genesis that are compatible with the scientifically determined ages of the Earth and universe and theistic evolution, which posits that the scientific principles of evolution, the Big Bang, age of the universe and age of Earth are compatible with a metaphorical interpretation of Genesis.

I am somewhat in favour of belief that the world will exist for 6000 years before the Second Coming of Christ. However it is impossible to pinpoint the exact year of a 6000 year conclusion even using the Ussher Chronology, due to the many variable in question!

The **Anno Lucis** more or less explains where I am going.

> [Anno Lucis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Lucis) (“in the Year of Light”) is a dating system used in Masonic ceremonial or commemorative proceedings, which is equivalent to the Gregorian year plus 4000. It is similar to Anno Mundi.
>
> For example, a date Anno Domini (AD) **2021** becomes Anno Lucis (AL) **6021**. This calendar era, which would designate 4001 BC as 'year zero', was adopted in the 18th century as a simplification of the Anno Mundi era dating system used in the Hebrew calendar and borrowing from other ideas of that time regarding the year of creation.
>
> After the Masoretic text was published, dating creation around 4000 BC became common, and it was received with wide support. Proposed calculations of the date of creation, using the Masoretic from the 10th century to the 18th century, were numerous and fluctuated by many decades. Notably, Isaac Newton's calculation pointed at the year 4000 BC.
>
> Among the Masoretic creation estimates or calculations for the date of creation, Archbishop Ussher's specific chronology dating the creation to 4004 BC became the most accepted and popular in Protestant Christendom, mainly because this specific date was attached to the King James Bible.

Personally, I am in favour of a year 2027-2030 as a fulfilling of the Year 6000 conclusion for the Second Coming of Christ. However calculations are impossible since the Gospels tell us  that we Will [**”not know the day or the hour”**](https://biblehub.com/matthew/25-13.htm) of the Lords return.

I am in favour of not including the years that Our Lord walked amongst men  in these 6000 year of history of mankind. Thus the Second Coming could be somewhere up to the Year 2033.

> Traditionally, English follows Latin usage by placing the "AD" abbreviation before the year number, though it is also found after that year. In contrast, BC is always placed after the year number (for example: AD 2021, but 68 BC), which preserves syntactic order. The abbreviation AD is also widely used after the number of a century or millennium, as in "fourth century AD" or "second millennium AD" (although conservative usage formerly rejected such expressions). Because BC is the English abbreviation for Before Christ, it is sometimes incorrectly concluded that AD means After Death, i.e., after the death of Jesus. However, this would mean that the approximate 33 years commonly associated with the life of Jesus would be included in neither the BC nor the AD time scales.
>
> The Anno Domini dating system was devised in 525 by Dionysius Exiguus to enumerate the years in his Easter table. His system was to replace the Diocletian era that had been used in an old Easter table, as he did not wish to continue the memory of a tyrant who persecuted Christians. The last year of the old table, Diocletian Anno Martyrium 247, was immediately followed by the first year of his table, Anno Domini 532. When Dionysius devised his table, Julian calendar years were identified by naming the consuls who held office that year— Dionysius himself stated that the "present year" was "the consulship of Probus Junior", which was 525 years "since the incarnation of our Lord Jesus Christ". Thus, Dionysius implied that Jesus' incarnation occurred 525 years earlier, without stating the specific year during which His birth or conception occurred. "However, nowhere in his exposition of his table does Dionysius relate his epoch to any other dating system, whether consulate, Olympiad, year of the world, or regnal year of Augustus; much less does he explain or justify the underlying date." -[Anno Domini](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini)

The actual 6000 year mark in actuality is impossible to narrow down with any exactitude!

Comment: Good background on year calculation, but it will be great if we can have some quotes from YEC / premillennialists dated later than 2000.  I agree with you on how [Easter 2033 is a big day](https://www.jc2033.world/en/) and being the 2,000 year anniversary makes a lot of sense to double as the Second Coming, and it's only less than 12 year away !