# Is there any biblical support for the world ending in 2029?

Tags: biblical-basis

There is a theory that the world ends in 2029.

There are 4000 years between Adam's creation and Christ's birth. Then, there is 2000 years between Christ's Crucifixion/Christ's Ascension/Pentecost and the year 2029. In total, these segments would span a 6000 years. Then, there is a millennium mentioned in the Book of Revelation, totaling the years of this age as 7000.

So, aside from the number 7, what biblical support is there for this theory? Also, how old is this theory?

Comment: One can juggle numbers in the bible to arrive at any year one cares to choose. This is just one of a multitude of similar opinions. _But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven, but my Father only_ is the truth. Matthew 24:26.

Comment: @NigelJ Sure, I understand that -- it's only a matter of time before grabbing numbers and operating on them yields a pleasant and even number. I'm just interested in the history of this specific theory, as it's a more recent one and may give insight to a fundamental misconception people have when approaching discerning when the end is.

Comment: There is no support for any such theories. I have given the text that contradicts all such theories.

Comment: @NigelJ I understand that that is your opinion, but I'm concerned with the genesis of the theory more than its accuracy. I'm not trying to support the idea, but to be clear a day and an hour are different from a season, a year, and a generation, excluding it from that verse if interpreted literally. Therefore, I think discussion of this theory is worthwhile.

Comment: Please [edit] this to give some quotes of Christians who teach this. We only allow Biblical Basis questions about the published teachings of Christians.

Comment: I sort of address this question in my response to this question: [According to post-2000 Young Earth Creationists / premillennialists, when do (did) we reach year 6000?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/84747/25495) I make the case of a possibility between 2027-2033!

Comment: A [related](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/115462) question.

Answer (score 3):

What some people call 'biblical support' is actually 'biblical interpretation'. That's because no verse anywhere in the Bible gives any date for when the world will end. On the contrary, it says:

> "Now we beseech you, brethren, by the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ,
> and by our gathering together unto him, that ye be not soon shaken in
> mind, or be troubled, neither by spirit, nor by word, nor by letter as
> from us, as that the day of Christ is at hand. Let no man deceive you
> by any means..." (2 Thessalonians 2:1-12 - do read the rest of these
> verses.)

The Bible does state that, one day, Christ will return to earth and then the Day of Judgment will start. Because the Day of Judgment is described in the Bible as a fearful and awe-inspiring day (period of time), it has become associated with "the end of the world" with catastrophe upon wicked people who reject the Son of God. Those who love God and trust in him have nothing to fear when Jesus returns in glory, with hosts of angels. They are aching for that day, to bring relief to God's people who undergo increasingly great tribulation in a godless world, leading up to Christ's sudden, unexpected appearing (Revelation 3:3).

So, it's entirely biblical for Christians to speak of the day Jesus returns to earth, to usher in the Day of Judgment. What they must never do is try to stick a date on to it! Sadly, lots of end-time denominations have done that, to their shame, for all their predicted dates have proven to be false. That makes them false prophets. The Bible warned that such false prophets would arise. Jesus said they would try to get people to follow them (into the desert, to see Christ there, or into their inner rooms). Read Matthew 24 vss 23-27 for that. And verses 35-36 has Jesus categorically stating,

> "Heaven and earth shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away.
> But of that day and hour knoweth no man, no, not the angels of heaven,
> but my Father only."

This means that ***whatever date anybody comes out with, claiming that will be when the world shall pass away, it will be wrong.*** It cannot be right, because only the Father knows the date, and he does not disclose when the time has come until the future prophecy is fulfilled in Revelation 14:14-20. That's still to be fulfilled, but nobody bar the Father knows when that time will come, and he's not telling any of us! Don't forget either, that the numbers stated in the Book of the Revelation are all symbolic, not literal. The two months, the 144,000, the 1,260 days, the 1,000 years... none of those numbers are literal. But all those vainly attempting to predict when Christ will return insist that the 1,000 years are a literal, future millennium, while saying other numbers are symbolic. Well, if that's how you treat the Bible, you're going to make it look like it agrees with whatever you interpret!

Here's another warning, from an astute Christian, Baptist preacher Charles Spurgeon, who said this in the late 1800s when lots of American denominations were getting preoccupied with end-time matters:

> "A strong indication of a bankrupt ministry is an emphasis on
> predictive prophecy."

Well, there's one explanation for you - groups majoring on end-time prophecy have a bankrupt ministry!

Comment: Hmm I'd be careful making blanket statements that numbers have no literal value...you clearly do not understand those which are very definately literal and those that are prophetic in the books of daniel and of revelation.

Comment: @Adam  I do know that literal numbers have literal value. I also know that many numbers in the Bible are meant to be taken literally. My point is that numbers in prophecies need to be seen as teaching spiritual truths and principles. Zechariah says 4 horses/chariots & Rev 4:8 has 4 living creatures: 4 represents the number of the whole earth, N.S.E.&W. 7 is heavenly perfection. 10 is completeness (10x10x10 = 1,000). 12 is the number of covenant. 144,000 = 12x12 thus both old and new covenants. 13 = number of times the 'dragon' appears in the N.T. That sort of thing.

Comment: @Adam  2- witness 3 - deity(with the emphasis on nature ?)  5 - pilgrimage (see Benjamin and portions) 6 - the number of humanity 7 - perfection 9 - deity (with the emphasis on person ?) 10 - completeness 12 - covenant/testament But as Anne says sometimes numbers have literal meaning. And sometimes, symbolic. . . . . .  and 153 fish in the boat ? ? ? ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a variant of **Millennial Day theory**.

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennial_Day_Theory)

This belief has surfaced frequently in Christian history. One reason for its repeated resurgence is the fact that we do not know when the Creation occured. Some in the early church followed the Septuagint translation for their chronologies. The age at death of many of the earliest people mentioned in the Bible in the Septuagint is much longer than that found in the Masoretic text. Because of this, many Christians originally thought that the six thousand years were up around 500-600 AD. Then people like Dionysius Exiguus, the Venerable Bede, and Bishop Ussher supplied new scholarship that pushed the Creation date forward. Thus we had millenarian hysteria between 1000 and 1100 AD, again in the 17th century, and at various intervals since then.

The chief support for these ideas springs from Genesis 1, where Creation occurs in seven days, and Second Peter:

> But do not overlook this one fact, beloved, that with the Lord one
> day is as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day. (2 Peter
> 3:8)

If the seventh day of creation is the sabbath day of rest, then the seventh "day" or millennium of history will be the "day" of rest. Some equate this to the millennial reign of Christ.

Even if this theory is correct, you have a problem. The theories attribute special events to each millennial day. Those events sometimes occurred at the beginning of the day - near the start of the corresponding millennium. However they sometimes occurred in the middle or near the end. Thus if Christ returns during the seventh millennium, we do not know whether it will be at the beginning or end of that period.

Nevertheless, here are a few observations to chew on:

1. **Adam's death.** The curse for eating the fruit of the tree of knowledge was "for in the day that you eat of it you shall surely die." Adam died 930 years later. If a day of judgment lasts a thousand years, then 930 calendar years falls just within the first millennial "day".
2. **Shortened lifespan.** *Then the Lord said, “My Spirit shall not abide in man forever, for he is flesh: his days shall be 120 years.”* (Genesis 6:3) Some claim that this meant God was shortening all human life to 120 years. Others claim this was not indicating the shortening of maximum human lifespan but a decree about when the flood would come - 120 years from the day of God's pronuncement. Can both be true? For this interpretation the latter group provide the simple evidence that after the flood, people continued to live longer than 120 years, though that age steadily dropped. However, who is the last human in the Bible to live 120 years? It was Moses, the giver of the God's law. God's law went in to full effect at that time. When did Moses die? At the very end of the thousand year period that began with God's pronouncement about the 120 year limit. Thus God's judgment against all humanity of shortening our lifespan further went into effect at the very end of that millennial "day" of judgment.
3. **The binding of Satan**. If any millennial theory is to be true, it has to make sense of other millennial statements. One biggie is the imprisonment of Satan, who will be set loose for a time near the end to fight the final battle. There are many ideas about this. Some have it happening in our future. Others claim it has already happened. Let's take one of the latter. Jesus said that to plunder a house, you first have to bind the strong man. Who is the strong man? The typical opinion is Satan, but what would be the physical manifestation of that? In the Bible, what are Satan's chief agents? Evil Human Empires! Of all the empires that ever existed, which lasted the longest and had a disproportionate impact on human history? Rome. What happened to Rome? God bound its most evil aspects (such as persecuting Christians) and turned it over to the Church to rule. When did the Church fully "bind" the Roman empire? In 380 AD, with the Edict of Thessalonica, making Christianity the state religion of the empire. What happened 1000 years later? Starting in the 1370's, the Ottoman Turks began a relentless campaign against the Eastern Roman Empire that led to its final collapse in 1453 with the fall of Constantinople. Among their earliest targets was Thessalonica. This is important because it was the first place in Europe visited by the Apostle Paul as well as the city named in the edict that bound Satan. With the fall of Constantinople, the prospect of reestablishing political unity among Christians vanished.

The above are not proofs, merely observations and correlations. Some millennial theory may be correct, but which one?

Comment: Whilst to God a day and a thousand years have no relevance...he is timeless, you make a gross error. The creation of the earth was not given in terms of an infinite God. Moses wrote it as measured in earthly time, the time of man. That very definately has specific days...it is as literal as Adam naming the animals!

Comment: @Adam - It was said of Jesus that he spoke in parables and said nothing that was not a parable. I do not dispute that the literal meanings are grounded in actual historical events, days and years counted in the normal way. However, Scripture is also given as a parable pointing to events yet to come and teaching deeper truths comprehended only after much study. Thus many persons and events are viewed as types representing things to come.

Answer (score -1):

The Bible's internal chronology is detailed enough that it is possible to calculate the year of Adam's creation. This, coupled with the statement at 2 Peter 3:8 that "a day is like a thousand years" to God has led some, at various times in history, to speculate that certain years will be significant by calculating how many millenniums have passed since Adam's creation.

However, such thinking is flawed - the creative 'day' did not end with the creation of Adam - it ended with the creation of *Eve*, and the Genesis account does not say how much time passed between the creation of the first two humans. We do not know Eve's age at her death, and so it is impossible to calculate the year that creation ended.

Further, consider the full text of 2 Peter 3:8: "*With the Lord a day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years are like a day*". This is **not** a statement of mathematics. It says that a day is like a thousand years, but the reverse is also true. So, which is it? Do we consider that each year is 365,000 years? Unlike some Biblical prophecies involving dates and times, this verse makes no mathematical sense. What it is simply saying is that our concept of time is meaningless to our infinite creator.

As Jesus said at Matthew 25:13: "*you do not know the day or the hour*".

Comment: Gross minterpretation of creation. I'd suggest starting out with the naming of the animals...it's very easy to determine the end of creation week!

Comment: What is indisputable is that there are seventy generations from Christ back to Adam as the genealogy of Luke makes clear.

Comment: @Adam Creation began "in the beginning", and it ended with Eve. Adam and his task of naming the animals came in-between. Can you name any new 'creation' after her?